# GravityForms to Salesforce API, problem with people who leave out company

Tags: plugins, plugin-gravity-forms

I use GravityForms in my WordPress site, and have the GravityForms to Salesforce API plugin that adds people who fill out a form as leads in Salesforce. It works fine, except for when people don't enter a company name. Is there a way to have it default to their full name if they don't enter a company?

Here's my code. I added alert boxes to help debug, but they don't even run!

```
add_filter('gform_after_submission_1', 'create_company_full_name', 10, 4); 
function create_company_full_name($entry, $form){ 
    $field_we_are_checking = '77'; 
    $name = $entry['1.3'].' '.$entry['1.4']; 

    if(empty($entry[$field_we_are_checking])){ 
        $entry[$field_we_are_checking] = $name; 
    } 
    return;
}
```

http://www.gravityforms.com/
http://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-salesforce/

UPDATE: Here's the code that worked in the end:

```
add_filter('gform_pre_submission_1', 'create_company_full_name', 10, 2);
function create_company_full_name($entry, $form){
    $field_we_are_checking = 'input_77';
    $name = $_POST['input_3'].' '.$_POST['input_4'];
    if(empty($_POST[$field_we_are_checking])){
        $_POST[$field_we_are_checking] = $name;
    }
    return;
}
```

where 1 (from `gform_pre_submission_1`) is the id of the form
and `input_77`, `input_3`, and `input_4` refer to the IDs of the fields in question (company, first name, last name)

Comment: You will get better response if you link to relevant resources, like the source code for the plugins in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thought is - why not make Company be required?

If that's not acceptable, there should be a way. I've not used this API, but have used other Gravity Forms hooks. Assuming you can hook in before it talks to the API, you should be able to check for the absence of one field, and replace it's value with that of another.

Example... bear in mind this is taken from another API for Gravity Forms.

```
add_filter('gform_pre_submission_1', 'user3515_function');
function user3515_function($form){
    $field_we_are_checking = 'input_77';
    $name = $_POST['input_3'].' '.$entry['input_4'];

    if(empty($_POST[$field_we_are_checking])){
        $_POST[$field_we_are_checking] = $name;
    }
    return;
}
```

EDITED

You'll obviously want to utilize the correct hook for your filter. **gform_pre_submission**  should be good, you'll have to test. You'll also need to supply the correct field names for company and name. You can learn those by looking at a completed result in phpmyadmin under gforms... lead detail I believe. Otherwise inspect in Chrome and it should tell you what field numbers each is.

Good luck, let me know if this gets you in the right direction.

Comment: I thought about making company be required, but for many people it wouldn't apply.

Comment: I think this is the right direction, but you totally lost me. From what I understand: I need to add a custom function that will run when they submit the form, that will check if company is blank, and if so, fill it with the first and last name. My questions: 1) Where do I put that PHP code? 2) How do I know which hook to apply it to? 3) Can I get the field numbers straight from gravityform's  gui?   THANKS!

Comment: Put it in your themes functions.php file, for example. This is probably the best hook as it hopefully runs before your third party plugin / add-on. http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_after_submission -- i already told you how to learn the form ids. Just view your html output to see their names. You want the numeric part.

Comment: Let me know if this works for you

Comment: I'm trying it now. Do I need to tell it to only do this if $form is the ID of the correct form?

Comment: yes, _or_ you can modify the hook with the id at the end, like this: `add_filter('gform_after_submission_12', ...)` where `12` should be replaced with the ID of the form.

Comment: Why am I sending 10 to $entry? Is that something I need to change?

Comment: forget that comment... I'm trying it now, I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working - it tells me that there was an entry sending the form to SF, and I don't see the company field in the entry.

Comment: Here's my code. I added alert boxes to help debug, but they don't even run! `add_filter('gform_after_submission_1', 'create_company_full_name', 10, 4);
function create_company_full_name($entry, $form){
    $field_we_are_checking = '77';
    $name = $entry['1.3'].' '.$entry['1.4'];
    alert($name);
    if(empty($entry[$field_we_are_checking])){
        $entry[$field_we_are_checking] = $name;
 alert("Updating company...");
    }
    return;
}`

Comment: alert? this isn't javascript. this is PHP. And all this is happening behind the scenes, so you're not going to see something echoing. if you want to debut this kind of stuff, write strings to files using a function such as [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). assuming $entry[1.3] and $entry[1.4] are your name field IDs, and that 77 is your company name field, this looks as though it should be working. Did you check your entries?

Comment: I took out the alerts. I checked the entries, and all of them have company blank. In the form in WP, the id of company is 77. What could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Oops. Wrong hook. Because we need to modify the value before it gets saved, not just do something with the value afterwards. See answer above, is updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's still erroring, though, and the GF entry's company is blank. This is what I saw in chrome's "inspect element" to get the id for first name: `id="input_1_3"`. Was I correct in assuming that its ID is ['1.3']?

Comment: After a bunch of testing and debugging and stuff, I got it to work! Here's the complete code: `add_filter('gform_pre_submission_1', 'create_company_full_name', 10, 2);
function create_company_full_name($entry, $form){
    $field_we_are_checking = 'input_77';
    $name = $_POST['input_3'].' '.$_POST['input_4'];
    if(empty($_POST[$field_we_are_checking])){
        $_POST[$field_we_are_checking] = $name;
    }
    return;`

Comment: Great to hear. Can you please mark this answer as correct?

Comment: I don't know if you'll see this, but I'm back and wondering if there's a way to do this for multiple forms, without making copies of all the code. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, change the hook name from `gform_pre_submission_1` to `gform_pre_submission`. It'll then run on everything unless you do a check inside to only run this given certain conditions, such as by form ID. you could also do the opposite of that. For example `if(!in_array($entry['form_id'], array(2,5)))` where 2 and 5 might be forms you _don't_ want processed.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I didn't know that _1 made it only run on form id 1.The complication here is that the field id's in question are different. maybe I can do that with switch...

Comment: How do I get the id of $form?

Comment: `$form['id']` http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Form_Object

Comment: thanks. For some reason, it's still not working. I have another thread running about this issue; if you feel like joining in you can find it here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128365/help-debugging-php-filter-for-wordpress#

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've seen last name is the only required field to create a record on the SF side. Could you remove the requirement for the company name on the field on the SF side?

Also you could add some conditional logic on the GF field for company, if the field is blank add the value of another field (create a hidden field with a default value of "unknown" for example) and send that value into SF.

Comment: Our salesforce is set up to require a company, I don't remember why. When people don't have a company, we just give it their full name.