# Help debugging PHP filter for wordpress

Tags: filters, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a PHP filter for wordpress/gravityforms, that just recently stopped working and I can't figure out why. Can anyone help me?

Here's the code:

```
add_filter('gform_pre_submission_2', 'create_company_full_name', 10, 2, 'input_7', 'input_6', 'input_1');

add_filter('gform_pre_submission_1', 'create_company_full_name', 10, 1, 'input_3', 'input_4', 'input_77');

add_filter('gform_pre_submission_26', 'create_company_full_name', 10, 26, 'input_7', 'input_6', 'input_9');

function create_company_full_name($entry, $form, $first, $last, $company){
    $field_we_are_checking = $company;
    $name = $_POST[$first].' '.$_POST[$last];
    if(empty($_POST[$field_we_are_checking])){
        $_POST[$field_we_are_checking] = $name;
    }
    return;
}
```

What it does/did is check if the person left the Company field blank, and if so, put the First and Last name in the Company field before submission. It does that for 3 different forms.

If I knew how to debug PHP, I would try it myself. But there's nothing like msgboxes or any other way to test things out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated!

Updated code:

```
add_filter('gform_pre_submission_1', 'create_company_full_name', 10, 2);
// 
function create_company_full_name($entry, $form){
    switch($form){
        case 1:
            $field_we_are_checking = $_POST['input_77']; 
            $name = $_POST['input_3'].' '.$_POST['input_4']; 
            break;
        case 2:
            $field_we_are_checking = $_POST['input_1']; 
            $name = $_POST['input_7'].' '.$_POST['input_6']; 
            break;
        case 26:
            $field_we_are_checking = $_POST['input_9']; 
            $name = $_POST['input_7'].' '.$_POST['input_6']; 
            break;
    }

     if(empty($_POST[$field_we_are_checking])){ 
         $_POST[$field_we_are_checking] = $name; 
     } 
     return;
}
```

Comment: which type of paramters should be add? @user3515

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the codex entry for [`add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter), you'll see there are 4 arguments for the function, the last being `$accepted_args`, which should be an *integer*. Your `add_filter` calls are not correct, so I'm not sure how they worked in the first place.

There appear to be 5 arguments in your hooked function, so I presume your `add_filter`s should be:

```
add_filter('gform_pre_submission_2', 'create_company_full_name', 10, 5);
add_filter('gform_pre_submission_1', 'create_company_full_name', 10, 5);
add_filter('gform_pre_submission_26', 'create_company_full_name', 10, 5);
```

That said, filters typically `return` a value, which your doesn't, so I can't say that's correct either, as I don't know Gravity Forms at all.

also see [Debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Comment: @user3515 That's all plain PHP and not WordPress specific. If you need help and Milo really wants to help you, then please open a [chat] room, else refer to php.net. Thanks. Cleaning that mess up now.

Comment: hello @milo, what should be the fifth argument to check that all details are filled?

Answer (score 0):

I take it the first block of code is the original (that used to do its job) and the second block of code is the new version that does something more, but doesn't work yet.

A thing that is wrong in the updated code is that `$field_we_are_checking` used to be the *name* of the field but here it is the *value* of a field.

In other words, replace

```
$field_we_are_checking = $_POST['input_77'];
```

with

```
$field_we_are_checking = 'input_77';
```

and so forth for the other two cases.

Also `$form` is a [form object](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Form_Object) and not a number, so

```
switch($form){
```

should be replaced by

```
switch($form['id']){
```

Comment: If it's an object, shouldn't it be `$form->id`? :)