# Console shows ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined, no clue why!

Tags: jquery, debug

I just installed FirePHP to help with debugging in WP, but for some reason all it shows is ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

I have some jquery stuff on the page that seems to be working just fine. I have no clue how to figure out why this error message is coming up - can anyone help me??

Thanks!

Comment: not without seeing the issue in context.

Comment: What kind of context?
Here's the page I see it on:
http://goinspire.com/trip-registration/?trip=Mens+Israel+Experience&CID=70180000000duVO

Comment: look at your page source, you have some code referencing the jquery object in head before the jquery script is embedded.

Comment: I looked at the source code, but don't how it's compiled/where it came from. This is a WP website that I inherited. How can I find what needs to be changed?

Comment: start by looking in the theme's `header.php`

Comment: Ok, I'm in there. I see script tags that contain 4 things that start with "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {".    Later on I see "<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>". Do I have to move it up?

Comment: [properly enqueued scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) are output by the `wp_head` function, inline scripts should appear after that function.

Comment: those scripts are after <?php wp_head(); ?>.

Comment: Here's my header.php - do you see anything wrong in there? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8240936 Thanks!

Comment: you'll have to look through your other theme files, starting with `functions.php` to find where all the javascript bits are being output. the offending code is probably hooked to the `wp_head` or `wp_print_scripts` action.

Comment: thanks. what am i supposed to be looking for?    also, do you think this issue is related to my other thread http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128365/help-debugging-php-filter-for-wordpress# ?